# Google Cloud Container Registry Issues while pushing docker images

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-container-registry

I have a Google project on which i am one of the owner. It was created by another developer and he added me as the owner. Now within that i created a VM instance within which i installed docker. After installing docker, i created an image of my node.js application by providing the git repository as the argument.

However after setting the gcloud config parameters, its giving me 500 error while trying to push that docker image

```
Error: Status 500 trying to push repository <project-id>/<image-name>: "Internal Error."
```

My gcloud and docker version information :-

- Google Cloud SDK 0.9.71
- Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

Comment: did you docker login, are you trying to push to docker hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably were hit by the Google Cloud Storage outage that was going on last night: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/storage/16027

would you mind trying again?

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Jeffrey van Gogh
Google Container Registry Team

Comment: It's on outage again? Seeing this again.